# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. Dynamic HTTP Endpoint Template does not work

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. I am making a rest call to a back-end service. For that i am using HTTP Endpoint template to make the dynamic endpoint. I am picking value from my URL and passing it to the endpoint.

**Sequence Code:**

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SampleSequence">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="uri.var.myProperty" expression="get-property('uri.var.identityCode')" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>

   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <http method="get" uri-template="http://com.example?identityCode={uri.var.myProperty}"></http>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

**Problem:**
The value is correctly being passed into property. But the endpoint is not picking it up. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Create the query string using REST_URL_POSTFIX[1] as follow

```
<property name="val1" expression="get-property('uri.var.identityCode')"/>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('?identityCode=',$ctx:val1)"  scope="axis2"/>

<send>
  <endpoint>
     <http method="get" uri-template="http://com.example"></http>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties

Comment: The documentation you link to specifically says **not** to do this in the case of an HTTP endpoint, but instead to do it as @omerkhalid asked in the original question is trying to do.  As far as I can tell, REST_URL_POSTFIX only works for "address" endpoints.

Comment: Hi,
 By using “uri.var.” and “POST_TO_URI” property we can achieve this for HTTP endpoint. can you look into the below?
https://susankhanirmala.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/how-to-appending-a-context-and-query-string-parameters-to-the-target-rest-endpoint-using-wso2-esb/